# How to install application to new samsung Smart tvs

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Hello I want to develop basic application for samsung smart tv for picture gallery. But im having troubles connecting the tv to my local server. As far as I red the information on the topics like this one I should have a local server and my developing machine and tv to be connected to same WIFI. This done. I have donwloaded SDKs with Eclipse from http://www.samsungdforum.com/devtools/sdkdownload . 
I was using this video tutorial :
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HppJHKwCGCo 
But tv im using is model 2014 and is with new tizen OS it has no button "More apps". So Im not able to reach the dialog where I should put my local server IP address. 
I have already set my "develop" account, but cant go forward to next step.

Any of you know how to make it. Thanks in advance and hope this is not duplicate problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow Samsung official guide to install Smart TV apps on Smart TV 2014 models:

[Testing Your Application on a TV for 2014](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=art00121&FileName=index.html)

Check if you're missing this step:

> "Long press the Enter button on remote control to any application. And enter the IP Setting."

Answer (score 0):

Those are the links with guidance for testing the following Samsung TV versions:

- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2011](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00013/index.html)
- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2013](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=d20&FileName=index.html)
- [Testing Your Application on a TV for 2014](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00121/index.html)